# IOS Ranging Beacon Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy, clregion

I am trying to scan and range nearby beacons. I've bought a nordic semiconductor nrf51822 ble but i cannot make it work. Even if i have the ble near me it doesn't see it at all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
   [self performSelector:@selector(startScanning) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState");
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber  numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
       [self.bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];       
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

 -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{
//NSLog(@"didDiscoverPeripheral %@ && UUID = ",peripheral.name, [peripheral.identifier UUIDString]);

    if(peripheral.name){
        [peripheral readRSSI];
        [self.beaconPeripherals addObject:peripheral];

        self.beacons = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.beaconPeripherals];

        [self reloadBeacons];
    }
}

- (void) startScanning{
    if(self.bluetoothManager){
        [self.bluetoothManager stopScan];
        [self.beaconPeripherals removeAllObjects];
    }

    self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
    self.beaconPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.beacons = [[NSArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
                      error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"RSSI update %@",peripheral.RSSI);
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManager delegates
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"*****didEnterRegion******");

    [self performActionForEvent:EventEnter withIdentifier:region.identifier];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
 {
     NSLog(@"***********didExitRegion***********");
     [self performActionForEvent:EventExit withIdentifier:region.identifier];
 }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
 {
     NSLog(@"didStartMonitoringForRegion");
 }

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
     NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
 }

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
 {
     NSLog(@"didRangeBeacons with size %i", beacons.count);
    if ([beacons count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"beacons founds: %lu",(unsigned long)[beacons count]);
        CLBeacon *beacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];


        NSLog(@"Beacons UUID: %@",beacon.proximityUUID);
        NSLog(@"Beacons Major: %@",beacon.major);
        NSLog(@"Beacons Minor: %@",beacon.minor);

        for(int i = 0; i < [beacons count]; i++) //scanned beacons in Ranging
        {
            for(int j=0; j<[self.beacons count]; j++) //stored beacons in database
            {
                 if (([[[beacons[i] proximityUUID] UUIDString] caseInsensitiveCompare:[((CBPeripheral *)self.beacons[j]).identifier UUIDString]]==NSOrderedSame) &&
                     ([[beacons[i] major] unsignedShortValue] == [[self.beacons[j] major] unsignedShortValue]) &&
                     ([[beacons[i] minor] unsignedShortValue] == [[self.beacons[j] minor] unsignedShortValue]) &&
                     ([[(Beacons *)self.beacons[j] enable]boolValue]))
                {
                     NSLog(@"Found Beacon and enabled");
                     NSLog(@"Beacon UUID: %@",[beacons[i] proximityUUID]);
                     NSLog(@"Beacon Major: %@",[beacons[i] major]);
                     NSLog(@"Beacon Minor: %@",[beacons[i] minor]);

                    //Finding Scanned Beacon Proximity and converting it to the Event of stored Beacon
                    if ([beacons[i] proximity] == CLProximityImmediate) {
                    NSLog(@"Immidiate Proximity: %@",beacon.proximityUUID);
                    [self.beaconsRange replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:At_Beacon]];
                    //[self.beaconsTableView reloadData];
                    if ([[self.beacons[j] event] isEqualToString:EventImmidiate]) {
                        NSLog(@"Close Event matched");
                       // [self performAction:[(Beacons *)self.beacons[j] action]];
                    }
                }
                else if ([beacons[i] proximity] == CLProximityNear) {
                    NSLog(@"Near Proximity: %@",beacon.proximityUUID);
                    [self.beaconsRange replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NEAR]];
                    //[self.beaconsTableView reloadData];
                    if ([[self.beacons[j] event] isEqualToString:EventNear]) {
                        NSLog(@"Near Event matched");
                        //[self performAction:[(Beacons *)self.beacons[j] action]];
                    }
                }
                else if ([beacons[i] proximity] == CLProximityFar) {
                    NSLog(@"Far Proximity: %@",beacon.proximityUUID);
                    [self.beaconsRange replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:FAR]];
                    //[self.beaconsTableView reloadData];
                }
                else if ([beacons[i] proximity] == CLProximityUnknown) {
                        NSLog(@"Unknown Proximity: %@",beacon.proximityUUID);
                        [self.beaconsRange replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UNKNOWN]];
                        //[self.beaconsTableView reloadData];

                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No beacon found!");
    }
}

 -(void)reloadBeacons
{
    if(!self.locationManager){
         self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
         // New iOS 8 request for Always Authorization, required for iBeacons to work!
         if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
         }
         self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
         self.locationManager.delegate = self;

         self.regions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS] count]];
         for (int index = 0; index < [[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS] count]; index++)
         {
            [self.regions addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
    }

    //[self.beaconsTableView reloadData];
    //This will put a delay of 5 seconds between Action trigger.
    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         if (shouldStopAction) { //If the view is disappeared then dont perfom Action
             isActionPerformed = YES;
         }
         else { //if the view is appeared then perform Action
             isActionPerformed = NO;
         }
     });

     self.beaconsRange = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.beacons count]];
     for (int index = 0; index < [self.beacons  count]; index++)
     {
         [self.beaconsRange addObject:[NSNull null]];
     }

    /*
     * Create Regions for each unique Beacon UUID provided in the app and these should be fixed and known
     * and assign each region unique identifier
     * if Beacon is saved with one of these provided UUIDs then register Region having that UUID
     * Unregister Region if there is not any saved or enabled Beacon found having that UUID
     */

     for(int regionIndex = 0; regionIndex < [[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS]count]; regionIndex++ )
    {
        BOOL isBeaconFound = NO;
        BOOL isBeaconEnable = NO;

        for(int beaconIndex = 0; beaconIndex < [self.beacons count]; beaconIndex++)
        {
            if ([[[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS] objectAtIndex:regionIndex] UUIDString]
                 caseInsensitiveCompare:[((CBPeripheral *)self.beacons[beaconIndex]).identifier UUIDString]]==NSOrderedSame) {
                isBeaconFound = YES;
                isBeaconEnable = YES;
            //
//                if ([[(Beacons *)[self.beacons objectAtIndex:beaconIndex]enable]boolValue]) {
//                isBeaconEnable = YES;
//                }
             }
        }
        //if Beacon/Beacons Found in Region (regionIndex) and
        //atleast one Beacon is enabled in that Region then check the corresponding Region
        // if Region is not exist already then create Region and start Monitoring and Ranging
        if (isBeaconFound && isBeaconEnable) {
             NSLog(@"Atleast one Beacon is enable in Region %d with UUID %@",regionIndex, [[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS]objectAtIndex:regionIndex]UUIDString]);
            if ([[self.regions objectAtIndex:regionIndex] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                NSLog(@"Creating Region %d with UUID %@",regionIndex,[[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS]objectAtIndex:regionIndex]UUIDString]);

                [self.regions replaceObjectAtIndex:regionIndex withObject:[Utility getRegionAtIndex:regionIndex]];

                [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:[self.regions objectAtIndex:regionIndex]];
                [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:[self.regions objectAtIndex:regionIndex]];
            }
            else {
                 NSLog(@"Region %d already exist with UUID %@",regionIndex,[[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS]objectAtIndex:regionIndex]UUIDString]);
            }
        }
        // if NO Beacon found or No Beacon is enable in Region (regionIndex) then check the corresponding Region
        // if Region exist already then stop Monitoring and Ranging and assign nil to Region
        else {
           NSLog(@"No beacon is found or enable in Region %d with UUID %@",regionIndex,[[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS]objectAtIndex:regionIndex]UUIDString]);

            if (![[self.regions objectAtIndex:regionIndex] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                 NSLog(@"Region %d with UUID %@ already exist and now removing it",regionIndex, [[[Utility getBeaconsUUIDS]objectAtIndex:regionIndex]UUIDString]);
                [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:[self.regions objectAtIndex:regionIndex]];
                [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:[self.regions objectAtIndex:regionIndex]];
                [self.regions replaceObjectAtIndex:regionIndex withObject:[NSNull null]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right enters in didEnterRegion but the size is always 0.

My plist is [image: PLIST]
  [image: desc]

Comment: Are you sure you have the right proximity UUID?  `01122334-4556-6778-899A-ABBCCDDEEFF0` seems awfully suspect to me.  If you're not sure, try downloading a generic "locate beacons" app (like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8)) that shows all nearby beacons, and see what the proximity UUID is.  If nothing shows up in that app, the problem is probably with your beacon.  If it does show up, the problem is likely with your code.  In that case, try plugging the UUID shown in the app into your code and see if it works.

Comment: For further information, I have found the answers to this question very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678379/why-doesnt-it-find-my-beacons.  In particular, the first two answers are great.  I'm not sure why the top, very detailed answer only has two up-votes, but mine is one of them. :)

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for your answer. The UUID might not be the correct one. How can i find the correct one?

Comment: As I mentioned, you should try downloading a generic "locate beacons" app (like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8)), and use it to detect your beacon.  It should tell you what the proximity UUID of that beacon is.  If you don't see any beacons detected in that app, the problem may be the beacon itself.  Also see the link to the other SO question I posted, with lots of additional information.

Comment: I should also mention that beacons will never be detected in the simulator, only with a real device (because the simulator would have to hijack the Bluetooth stack on your Mac).

Comment: I have used another app and modified it in order to search for all the beacons and indeed the UUID was not correct but the problem persists and the app never enters in didEnterRegion.

Comment: Also i am using a Iphone 6+ ios8.4

Comment: Update. changed the code and does enter in didEnterRegion but the size is always 0 event if i have the beacon near me.

Comment: Where is size 0?  I do not see size in the code.

Comment: Did you request permission to range beacons?  Do you have the appropriate properties set in `Info.plist`?  Please ensure that you have followed all the steps in the [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678379/why-doesnt-it-find-my-beacons) I posted.

Comment: I have Updated my answer in order to have a better view. Please let me know if something is missing. Thank you :)

Comment: @davidgyoung He means beacons.count, not size. I'm having the same issue